# Xamarin - shared storage class for each platform

Tags: xamarin, save, load, storage

I'm currently discovering Xamarin and what I try is to save some data.
I searched on internet and I found some tutorials interesting like this [one](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/data-storage-using-xamarin.html) and this [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/application-class/) given by Xamarin (Properties Dictionary).

However, I don't understand some things. I developed under Android and WinPhone(8.1, UWP) some apps and to store data, I used SharedPreferences (Android) which is a system of keys/string and XML files (serializer/deserializer) (WinPhone).

For this Xamarin application, I want to make a storing class which work for all platforms. After searches, I didn't find something that I can use on each platform.

**Application.Current.Properties["id"] = someClass.ID;**

By exemple, I tried to use this code to store data and... the only 'using' (Visual Studio 2015) that I found was about Android..

My goal is to make a class like that

```
public class Storage
{
    public void storeUser(User user)
    {
        Application.Current.Properties["username"] = user.username;
    }

    public User loadUser()
    {
        User user = new User();

        //Fill user with data

        return (user);
    }
}
```

I want that this class be a "shared code class" which can save data into a file or anything else (it doesn't bother me) and which can be declared anywhere in my code. Then I want to be able either on Android or iOS or WinPhone to call Storage.storeUser(user); as simply as it's explained above.

Thank for reading and help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im assuming that your using xamarin.forms since your linking to that documentation.

I use the PCLStorage by Daniel Plaisted. you can find it on NuGet.

I usually do it in a static class with the two methods below. Add the PCLStorage NuGet package to your PCL and add

```
Using PCLStorage
```

you wanna deserialize your object and pass the string to this service... when your reading content you just serialize it back to the object. easy peasy :)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Reads content from a file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">the name of the file</param>
    /// <param name="foldername">the name of the folder containing the file</param>
    /// <returns>string of the read content</returns>
    public static async Task<string> ReadFileContent(string filename, string foldername)
    {
        var rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
        IFolder specificFolder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync(foldername, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        await specificFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        ExistenceCheckResult exist = await specificFolder.CheckExistsAsync(filename);

        string text = null;
        if (exist == ExistenceCheckResult.FileExists)
        {
            IFile file = await specificFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
            text = await file.ReadAllTextAsync();
        }
        return text;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes content to a file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">the name of the file</param>
    /// <param name="foldername">the name of the folder containing the file</param>
    /// <param name="content">The content to be written to the file</param>
    /// <returns>returns true</returns>
    public static async Task<bool> WriteFileContent(string filename, string foldername, string content)
    {
        var rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
        IFolder specificFolder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync(foldername, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        ExistenceCheckResult exist = await specificFolder.CheckExistsAsync(filename);

        string text = null;
        if (exist == ExistenceCheckResult.FileExists)
        {
            IFile file = await specificFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
            await file.WriteAllTextAsync(content);
        }
        else
        {
            IFile file = await specificFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            await file.WriteAllTextAsync(content);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

if you wanna improve it you could throw in some error handling like a catch and try block. But i havent had any issues.

if you need to store sensitive data you can also use the securestorage from xlabs.
https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs

im actually using both in my application. Best of luck

Comment: Thank for your answer ! :) I took a look, tried your code and adapted it to my code. However, I got an error which is "System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing." I searched from where it could comes but I didn't really find from where this error could comes.. Anyway, it's all about xml so maybe I didn't understand something ;)

Comment: Are you trying to do something with XML? Sounds Like an error from trying to serialize XML or something. Try setting some breakpoints and debug your way through too see where the error occures

Comment: Yes I try to serialize to get my object converted into string to use your 2 functions ;)

Comment: If you have a c# object the easiest way to make that into a string is with a Json serializer. There is alot of those. Cant remember which one im using tho

Comment: "using Newtonsoft.Json" is really easy to use :)
Thank a lot dude !

Answer (score -1):

Try this plugin

https://components.xamarin.com/view/SettingsPlugin

Don't rewrite the history ...